# Logical OR in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logical-or

I ran into a case where I have run both functions in a JavaScript or expression:

```
function first(){
    console.log("First function");
    return true;
};

function second(){
    console.log("Second function");
    return false;
};

console.log(!!(first()||second()));
```

In this case it will output:

> "First function"
>
> true

In C# there is a logical (|) OR that is different from a conditional or (||) that will make sure both expressions are evaluated:

```cs
Func<bool> first = () => { Console.WriteLine("First function"); return true; };
Func<bool> second = () => { Console.WriteLine("Second function"); return false; };
Console.WriteLine(first() | second());
```

This will output:

In this case it will output:

> "First function"
>
> "Second function"
>
> true

I can't seem to find any info on how to implement the same logic in JavaScript without running the expressions beforehand:

```
function first(){
    console.log("First function");
    return true;
};

function second(){
    console.log("Second function");
    return false;
};

var firstResult = first();
var secondResult = second();

console.log(firstResult||secondResult);
```

Is there a way I can implement a C# logical OR in JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: "C# logical OR" that's a bitwise or, not a logical or.

Comment: Did you try `|` [Bitwise or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_OR))

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: `|` is either a bitwise OR **or** [a logical OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-or-operator-) in C# (and many other languages), depending on context. When used as a logical or it's the non-shortcut version.

Comment: @JoachimSauer ok, but it's not usually referred as such. I mean, sure `false | true` and `false || true` are semantically the same, but there's a difference on how they operate. EDIT: per your comment on MrGreek's answer, I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: yet they are both logical ORs. Granted, the non-shortcut logical OR isn't used a lot (since there's barely a reason to), but it's definitely not a bitwise OR.

Comment: Non-shortcut boolean operators in javascript are `+` for OR and `*` for AND.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `|` (`Bitwise OR`):

```js
function first(){
    console.log("First function");
    return true;
};

function second(){
    console.log("Second function");
    return false;
};

console.log(!!(first()|second()));
```

Read more about [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (`||`, `!!`, etc...) and [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) (`|`, `&`, etc...) in JavaScript.

Comment: Note that it's not quite the same as in C#: In C# the `|` is used as a non-shortcut logical operator in this case, whereas it's *always* a bitwise OR in JavaScript. You can use it in a similar way, but it doesn't quite behave the same way.

Comment: I like your answer, but rather than using console.log(!!(first()|second())); I would use console.log(!!(!!first() | !!second())); just in case the functions return something else other than a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

You could call all functions by collecting the values and then check the values.

```js
function first(){
    console.log("First function");
    return true;
}

function second(){
    console.log("Second function");
    return false;
}

console.log([first(), second()].some(Boolean));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function logicalOr(a, b) {
   return a || b;
}
```

...

```
logicalOr(first(), second());
```

If you call this with functions they evalualed before reaching the or statement.

Comment: This is actually the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bitwise or Operator and cast the result to a boolean

```
let a = () => {console.log("a"); return true}
let b = () => {console.log("b"); return false}
console.log(!!(a()|b()))
```

This outputs

> a
>
> b
>
> true

Answer (score 1):

You are using a bitwise logical operator in **c#** and conditional OR operator in **JavaScript**.

use the bitwise logical operator which evaluates both and outputs as expected.

`console.log(!!(first()|second()));`

Answer (score 1):

```
function first(){
    console.log("First function");
    return true;
};

function second(){
    console.log("Second function");
    return false;
};

console.log(!!(first() | second()));
```

// Instead Use this